# How is Memory Organized in Windows?

Tags: windows, memory, memory-management

I'm looking for an explanation or good free online resources about the organization of memory and memory management in Windows systems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can buy this (old) book, (the actual Windows architecture hasn't really changed much in 10 years) for a penny (used):

[Inside Windows NT](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1572316772)

Here's the up-to-date version:

[MS Windows Internals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619174)

There's also [Mark's Blog](http://blogs.technet.com/markrussinovich/)

As far as ONLINE resources go, I've found it to be pretty sparse, though :(

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this](http://www.dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx?showNum=361) DotNet Rocks podcast on the Windows memory model

Answer (score 1):

In MSDN, some information is located here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366525(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Windows Internals is the canonical reference for mm. It's far better than anything else you'll find on the subject, as Landy Wang doesn't write too much :)